# How would you convert this to an iterative function instead of recursive with a nested loop?

Tags: c#, recursion, iteration

The below functions results in hundred of levels of recursion.  I'm wondering if anybody has a suggestion on how to switch this to a loop function instead.  I believe the order of execution does matter in this case, but I may need to do more of an investigation.  I was hoping I could directly convert it to an iterative function instead of recursion.

As you can hopefully see, the only parameter passed to each level of recursion is "after".  So the recursive function call itself is relatively simple, but the loop surrounding the call is what throws me off.

I've considered doing a queue, but the condition of "changed" seems to imply depth first checks.  I'd have to perform part of the shifting operation prior to adding it to the queue, but in the current code the next level of recursion would start immediately after, so I can't just build up a queue of items to process and execute them in order.

I've considered a stack, but I'm not sure how I'd go about implementing that to replace the recursion.

I decided to simplify the code, as it probably was a bit confusing.  Here's a skeleton (that you could actually run if you initialize the variables!) that's probably more "psuedo" like

```
    private void DataChangedRecursive(LinkedNode node)
    {
        InitializeVariables();
        try
        {
            foreach (LinkedNode after in node.After)
            {
                var afterDetails = after.Before;
                bool changed = CheckData(afterDetails);

                if (changed)
                {
                    DataChangedRecursive(afterDetails);
                }
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            // Assume relavant error handling at this level in the stack.  This probably isn't important to maintain, but it'd be interested if we could.
            throw;  
        }
    }
    
    public object InitializeVariables()
    {
        // Assume relavant work happens here.
        return new object();
    }
    
    public bool CheckData(LinkedNode dr)
    {
        // Logic is that something changes, so it needs to save.  This does a bunch of comparisons on the current item.
        return dr.DataChanged;
    }
    
    public class LinkedNode
    {
        public LinkedNode Before {get;set;}
        public bool DataChanged {get;set;}
        public List<LinkedNode> After {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: Out of interest: Why was the solution implemented as a recursive function in the first place?

Comment: This is an excellent question, deserving a good answer and lots of upvotes!

Comment: @Zimano I'm not sure.  This is one of the oldest blocks of code in our solution.  The way it works is that each schedule is linked to a predecessor and a postcessor.  I assume they did recursion thinking it was the easiest way to traverse to the next level, in a specific order.  I've drawn it on a board, and it's basically like a binary tree, where the right most branch is complete first, then the next immediate branch left.  Here's a picture of how it traverses: [link](https://imgur.com/a/dislBFf).

Comment: The best way to look at it is that it performs the children nodes prior to completing the parent nodes.  While processing the root, it moves to the right child, then before completing the right child, completes it's right child, etc.  Until all children nodes are complete, then the parent node is run.

Comment: how about a while loop until drPost.GetParentRow("schedulePredecessors") is null ...that means you should stop?...keep moving up the tree until you hit the root node?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 How do I mimic doing all the logic of the recursion?  The drPost comes from a list of children that end up being part of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, had an epiphany about it.  Turns out the easiest way to deal with recursion and a loop is to take advantage of IEnumerator.  It requires that you manually deal with the iteration (no for loops), but the order of the recursion and loops will be identical.

I split the function into two parts, the entry function and the function to do the iteration along with the "recursion".  Essentially, this will guarantee all of the children are fully complete first, just like the recursion, and return to the correct iteration point in the parent.  This should theoretically work for any recursive function with a loop inside it.

```
private void DataChangedRecursive(LinkedNode node)
{
    try
    {
        DataChanged(node);
    }
    catch 
    {
        throw;  
    }
}

private void DataChanged(LinkedNode node)
{
    var state = new Stack<IEnumerator<LinkedNode>>();
    state.Push(node.After.GetEnumerator());

    while (state.Count > 0)
    {
        InitializeVariables();
    
        while (state.Peek().MoveNext())
        {
            ItemWithPredPostcessor after = state.Peek().Current;
            ItemWithPredPostcessor afterDetails = after.Before;
            bool dataChanged = StartShift(afterDetails);

            if (dataChanged)
            {
                Save(afterDetails);
                state.Push(afterDetails.After.GetEnumerator());
            }
        }
        state.Pop(); // Remove current from list, as we've completed.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a section in memory, called the [stack](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-memory-stack). Function calls are stored in the stack. Considering that your f function calls a g function, the g function is pushed to the stack. When g is executed, it will be popped from the stack and its result - if any - will be returned to f at the location where f has been interrupted to call and execute g.

This behavior is automatic, but if you understand it - and I advise you to read some articles about it - then you will realize what behavior you will need to emulate. Yes, your thought that you need a stack is true. Each item in your stack will have to store the state, that is, you will need to make sure that whenever you push a new item to your stack you do not forget the state of the interrupted item you were at before pushing a new item to the stack. Also, when you pop an item from a stack, you will need to ensure that its result (in this case you have void, so you will not care about the result, but I'm speaking in general terms) is given back correctly to the new top of the stack after the pop. You will also need to accurately get back to the correct state after the pop. So you will need to carefully handle your variables.

Now, let's see how should it work. For each level you have a queue of potential new levels. In our case you will need a cycle which will handle a step in each iteration. A step can be an initialization, a queue item handling, a pop. The cycle will run until the stack gets empty, so make sure that your stack will get empty eventually to avoid some frustrations. To know what you need to do you will need to have a state for each level of your stack, so your program will always know whether a given item was already initialized, its queue is being iterated or not or is it to be finalized. The queue is the set of possible sub-items. A very simplified pseudocode to illustrate the idea:

```
root.state <- preinitialized
stack.push(root);
while (not stack.empty()) do
    item <- stack.top()
    if (item.state = preinitialized) then
        item.initializeQueue()
        item.queueIterator.initialize()
        item.state <- queue
    else if (item.state = queue) then
        if (item.queueIterator.hasNext()) then
            next <- item.queueIterator.next()
            if (someCondition) then
                next.state <- preinitialized
                stack.push(next)
            end if
        else
            item.state <- finished
            result <- stack.pop(item)
            if (stack.top()) then
                stack.top.apply(result)
            else
                finalResult <- result
            end
        end if
    end if 
end while
```

Comment: That would work if it wasn't a loop inside a recursive function.  The answer isn't that trivial.  For each level of recursion, there's a potentially unlimited number of children that also trigger another level of recursion.  Converting straight to a stack isn't possible... The closest thing I could think of was using a Queue, but then the order of schedules are maintained, but the order of the processing would be different.

Comment: @Knodel12 it seems I did not formulate my answer in an understandable manner. I have meant that we have a stack and on each level we have a queue. If you take a look at the pseudocode again while keeping this in mind, you will realize that my answer actually handles the problem you raised. However, the fact that it was misunderstandable must be fixed, so whatever was not clear in the answer or misleading gramatically, please, let me know so I will reformulate those parts to make it more understandable.

Comment: I'm struggling to implement your solution.  What is queueIterator?  What is the state?

Comment: Also, what is apply?  And result?

Comment: @Knodel12 queueIterator is an iterator with which you can iterate a queue. Since there are infinitely many ways to use a queue in C#, I trusted your choice of how it should be handled. But since apparently queueIterator was unclear, I think it is feasible to give you an example. Let's suppose you are using the Queue class. In this case you can add elements to the end of the queue via the Enqueue method and get elements from the head of the queue via the Dequeue method.

Comment: @Knodel12 if you choose to use Queue, then queueIterator.hasNext() can be implemented as a comparison of Count > 0. Instead of queueIterator.next() you can use the Dequeue method and initializing your queue will change accordingly as well. The pseudocode in the answer is a means to share the idea. Do not take it literally, when I write queueIterator, the aim is to make you understand that we need a pausable way of iteration and I do not really focus on the actual data structures you will use. State is the state of a given level in the stack. It is a vital information to know whether

Comment: @Knodel12 that level was just created anew and needs initialization, or it is iterating the queue, or was it finished. Again, I do not really care about the actual implementation of state. You could use an Enum for this purpose, or whatever suits you best.

Comment: @Knodel12 apply and result are tools to handle the return value of a recursive function. Since in your case the method is void, you will not have to apply its result to the previous level, nor handle any final results. But if your method was not void, then these would be needed.

Comment: @Knodel12 I understand that you want to solve your concrete problem, but it is an advanced topic. Since others in the future might have similar problems, but maybe not even in .NET, or not void methods, I did a level of abstraction to ensure that the answer is as general as possible.